# Puppet fact for fqdn doesn't return the fully qualified domain name

Tags: puppet

I've set a hostname which excludes a domain name I've been provided with. However when it connects to my puppet master, lots of code fails - eventually I've pinned this down the fqdn fact not returning the fully qualified domain name and instead returning the hostname. Is there anyway around this? Perhaps it's a misconfiguration in puppet or changes to the agent.

If there isn't, what can I do to resolve it? Should I create a new fact? Find and replace everywhere the fqdn fact is use.

```
[root@a /]# hostname
a.long.hostname.with.lots.of.required.fields
[root@a /]# hostname -f
a.long.hostname.with.lots.of.required.fields.areallongexample.com
[root@a /]# facter fqdn
a.long.hostname.with.lots.of.required.fields
[root@a /]# facter hostname
a
[root@a /]# facter domain
long.hostname.with.lots.of.required.fields
[centos@a ~]$ facter networking.fqdn
a.long.hostname.with.lots.of.required.fields
[centos@a ~]$ facter networking
{
  dhcp => "192.168.0.2",
  domain => "long.hostname.with.lots.of.required.fields",
  fqdn => "a.long.hostname.with.lots.of.required.fields",
  hostname => "a",
  interfaces => {
    eth0 => {
      bindings => [
        {
          address => "192.168.0.2",
          netmask => "255.255.255.0",
          network => "192.168.0.0"
        }
      ],
      dhcp => "192.168.0.1",
      ip => "192.168.0.2",
      mac => "00:00:00:00:00:00",
      mtu => 9001,
      netmask => "255.255.255.0",
      network => "192.168.0.0"
    },
    lo => {
      bindings => [
        {
          address => "127.0.0.1",
          netmask => "255.0.0.0",
          network => "127.0.0.0"
        }
      ],
      ip => "127.0.0.1",
      mtu => 65536,
      netmask => "255.0.0.0",
      network => "127.0.0.0"
    }
  },
  ip => "192.168.0.2",
  mac => "00:00:00:00:00:00",
  mtu => 9001,
  netmask => "255.255.255.0",
  network => "192.168.0.0",
  primary => "eth0"
}
```

Comment: Could you include the output of 'facter fqdn', 'facter networking.fqdn' and 'facter networking' (delete anything you don't want to make public). This is the gem that provides facter https://rubygems.org/gems/facter I'm looking at the code (there is a link on that page to it) that creates the fqdn and on Linux it looks like it just gets the hostname and domain name and joins them together to create networking.fqdn and then just adds an alias fqdn to allow you to get to it directly.

Comment: I'll add these now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a fact called fqdn and changed the weight for it, it simple runs hostname -f.

Answer (score 0):

> I've set a hostname which excludes a domain name I've been provided with.

No, you haven't.  At least not if the `hostname` outputs you present model the actual system configuration correctly.  You've configured the machine with a hostname that expresses a *different* domain name than you were given.

A fully-qualified domain name consists of a series of segments separated by periods (`.`).  The first segment is a machine-specific name, and the rest is a domain name.

It is valid and common to configure a machine such that the `hostname` command returns the fully-qualified domain name, and I find this easiest to work with from a Puppet perspective.  Some people prefer to instead configure such that the `hostname` command returns the simple hostname, and this can work, too, provided that the  `dnsdomainname` command returns the full domain.

Facter assumes that one of those two approaches has been taken, but the outputs of your `hostname` and `hostname -f` commands show that your machine is configured differently.  `hostname` returns a name that looks like a FQDN on account of containing period-separated segments, but it is not the machine's FQDN.  This will very likely cause trouble for more than just Puppet and Facter, which is why it is reasonable for Facter assume that machines are not configured the way yours is.

You should fix your system configuration.  If the machine's correct FQDN is `a.long.hostname.with.lots.of.required.fields.areallongexample.com` then you should set either that or simply `a` as (its sense of) its hostname.  This may require you to dump your current Puppet machine registration and re-register with the new hostname.

Comment: I can't do that, there's a physical limitation on the number of characters a hostname/fqdn can have. I've been provided with a long root domain which I've got no control over and the hosts have a "hostname" (or fqdn) with elements (separated by dots) to break down their purpose and function (controlled by puppet).

Dnsdomainname will consistently return everything after the first dot which *isn't* the root53 domain I've been allocated (in this case: 
[centos@a ~]$ dnsdomainname
long.hostname.with.lots.of.required.fields.areallongexample.com

).

Comment: @keeer, again, the naming configuration you describe is neither standard nor supported by Puppet.  As I said, it is likely to cause you trouble elsewhere, too.  If you want a simple hostname that is made up of delimited segments then choose a different delimiter, such as the hyphen (`-`).